# KnockoutJS - jQuery Mobile Range Slider not updating

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I have a observable called foo and then a computed that is interconnected with foo

```
foo = ko.observable();
bar = ko.computed(function(){
    read: function() {
        var blah = parseFloat(self.foo()),
            qux = blah + 1;

        return qux;
    },
    write: function(value)
    {
        value = parseFloat(value);
        self.foo(value - 1);
    },
});
```

I have this textfield

```
<input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" placeholder="Foo" class="border-bottom" data-bind="value: foo"/>
```

And I have this jQuery Mobile Range Slider

```
<input class="ratio" type="range" name="slider-percent" min="0.00" max="100.00" data-highlight="true" step="0.1" data-bind="value: bar"/>
```

and then a debugging markup for KO

```
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Here are some problems that I have

1. When I update `foo` textfield, I see that the value of `bar` changes via the debugging markup but it does not reflect in the actual slider.
2. When I try to move slider around, nothing happens. Neither `foo` nor `bar` gets updated.

Is there a way to solve this problems?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r7Ruc/1/

There was an extra function() in the computed declaration. If you use both read and write, you should pass an object to computed, not a function.

The code, because of "Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code."

```
var CTR = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.foo = ko.observable();
    self.bar = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            var blah = parseFloat(self.foo()),
                qux = blah + 1;

            return qux;
        },
        write: function (value) {
            console.log(value);
            value = parseFloat(value);
            //self.share(value - 1);
        },
    });
}
var c = new CTR();
ko.applyBindings(c);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response pax162. I tested the jsfiddle. It seems to me that when I move slider around, it still doesn't update the `foo` observable. My goal with this 2 variables is that if one changes, the other is updated. While your code updates when `foo` is changed, `foo` is not updated when I moved slider around.

Comment: I changed `self.share(value-1)` since it is supposed to be `self.foo(value-1)`. I am not sure why you are commenting it though. I uncommented it and then it worked fine in jsfiddle.

Comment: Another thing is that I am using jQuery Mobile. Shouldn't that be included in the jsfiddle?

Comment: Well, it worked, probably jquery/jqueryui is already included in the page

Comment: I am using jQuery Mobile, not jQuery or jQuery UI. I checked the jsfiddle and it doesn't seem to be included, since the slider should look different.

Comment: Got it, the slider is the range input from html 5: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_range